# restore errors in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, restore

I am trying to restore my server back. I have full backup and a backup of the one of my web applications which is sharpeoint-81.

I perform the restore as explained on Microsofts site, I get many cannot restore errors. (see below) does anyone have any idea why I get those?

[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object UpdateHiddenListJobDefinition because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.UpdateHiddenListJobDefinition, Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object SharePoint Server State Service Proxy because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.StateServiceProxy, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object State Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.StateServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Microsoft SharePoint Server Diagnostics Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.DiagnosticsService, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Global Search Settings because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Application Registry Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryService, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Application Registry Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceApplication, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Application_Registry_Service_DB_ba089f01c152413c8d53a3c5c4a9efa9 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceDatabase, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Application Registry Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Access Services because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.MossHost.AccessServerWebServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.Access.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Secure Store Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Secure_Store_Service_DB_a485baec29384824a78d4d21d9115487 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceDatabase, Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object PerformancePoint Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplication, Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringService, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object PerformancePoint Service Application_7e036319dd5e430bbd84d1e3ebc38577 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceDatabase, Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringService, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Visio Graphics Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.Administration.VisioGraphicsServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Managed Metadata Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplication, Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Managed Metadata Service_97d36455087841c4823948df14d57ea7 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceDatabase, Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Web Analytics Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_StagingDB_c0dd6078-a2c3-4218-b97b-fa068e544192 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsStagerDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ReportingDB_b124f210-9650-41af-ab56-529d9bba1240 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsWarehouseDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Excel Services Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.ExcelServerWebServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Word Automation Services because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Service.WordServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.Word.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object WordAutomationServices_6897378abff842fe8c5f4655336e54ee because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Service.QueueDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Word.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB_bce460fc1d504ee0a4816fbc81e9df69 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_SyncDB_7a83b4225a4e4132a9c7a3258e91661b because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SynchronizationDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_SocialDB_073da1492bb649b39f828e85696a5b6e because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SocialDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_LanguageSynchronizationJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication+LanguageSynchronizationJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ILMProfileSynchronizationJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_UserProfileChangeJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileChangeJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_ProfileImportJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_UserProfileChangeCleanupJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileChangeCleanupJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_MySiteSuggestionEmailJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MySiteEmailJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_ActivityFeedCleanupJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityFeedCleanupUPAJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_ActivityFeedJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityFeedUPAJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_AudienceCompilationJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceCompilationJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application_SocialDataMaintenanceJob because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.SocialData.SocialDataMaintenanceJob, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Search Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Search_Service_Application_DB_46e99bec4d3143f8a058d02ebf559e6c because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Admin (C: on OPS5) because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRAdminComponent, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_9986db5a33714ebea63b6437e8a50f53 because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchGathererDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Search_Service_Application_PropertyStoreDB_ca611ebfb79642fd9546f5373006a17e because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchPropertyStoreDatabase, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Word Automation Services because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Service.WordServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.Word.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Managed Metadata Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object PerformancePoint Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.ServerCommon, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Secure Store Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Search Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Web Analytics Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object User Profile Service Application because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
[2/21/2012 12:15:53 PM] Warning: Cannot restore object Visio Graphics Service because it failed to initialization. Initialization error message: Cannot locate class information for: Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.Administration.VisioGraphicsServiceApplicationProxy, Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.